# Add a root element to a XML

Tags: java, xml, xmlroot

I'm quite a noob, since I don't have any previous knowledge of java programming.

Said that, I've managed to arrange some code into a working txt to xml converter.

Please take extreme consideration of the following note:

I have no clue at all about the building of the code, see it as someone who look for each piece from a different page and merge it together with, not a little, but a lot of help. Remind of that prior to report this question. Thanks

Given the following code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;

import com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream;
import com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.xml.DomDriver;
import com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.xml.XmlFriendlyNameCoder;

public class xml{

static class Bean {
    int id;
    String firstname;
    String lastname;
    String mail;

    public Bean(int id, String firstname, String lastname, String mail) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.firstname = firstname;
        this.lastname = lastname;
        this.mail = mail;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFirstname() {
        return firstname;
    }

    public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
    }

    public String getLastname() {
        return lastname;
    }

    public void setLastname(String lastname) {
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }

    public String getMail() {
        return mail;
    }

    public void setMail(String mail) {
        this.mail = mail;
    }
}

private XStream xstream = new XStream();

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    new xml().process();
}

private void process() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {

    xstream.alias("item", Bean.class);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("\\test.txt"));
    try {
        String line = br.readLine();
        line = br.readLine();
        while (line != null) {
            String[] split = line.split("\t");
            Bean bean = new Bean(new Integer(split[0]), split[1], split[2], split[3]);
            createBeanFile(bean);
            line = br.readLine();
        }
    } finally {
        br.close();
    }

}   

private void createBeanFile(Bean bean) throws IOException {

    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter
            (new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream("\\test.xml"),"UTF-8"));
    String str = xstream.toXML(bean);
    bw.write(str);
    bw.close();
    }
}
```

How and where can I add a root element in order to modify my current ouput from this:

```
<item>
  <id>56885</id>
  <firstname>LYTF</firstname>
  <lastname>LPRT</lastname>
  <mail>LYTF_LPRT@DERP.COM</mail>
</item>
```

To this:

```
<root>
    <item>
      <id>56885</id>
      <firstname>LYTF</firstname>
      <lastname>LPRT</lastname>
      <mail>LYTF_LPRT@DERP.COM</mail>
    </item>
</root>
```

Comment: I know that adding DocumentBuilderFactory along with some Element root will do the trick, but certainly I have no clue whatsoever of where to put it or how to arrange the existing code.

Comment: You can't until you understand what this piece of _Arranged Code_ doing and how

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would urge you to study how the [XStreams library works](http://xstream.codehaus.org/tutorial.html) instead of copying existing *(badly implemented code)* and try to modify it to your needs.

What you could do is to add a root class, which holds collection of your items.

```
static class Root{

    List<Item> item = new ArrayList<Item>();

    public List<Item> getitem() {
        return item;
    }

    public void setBeans(List<Item> item) {
        this.item = item;
    }
}
```

in your process method, you then set the following properties to xStream.

```
xstream.alias("root", Root.class);
xstream.alias("item", Item.class); //I renamed the bean class to item here.
xstream.addImplicitCollection(Root.class, "item");
```

and in your while loop, you would then add the items to the root class and write out the XML after the loop.

```
while (line != null) {
            String[] split = line.split(",");
            Item item = new Item(new Integer(split[0]),split[1]);
            root.getitem().add(item);
            line = br.readLine();
        }

        createBeanFile(root);
```

Hopefully this will get your started.